# Google Play Store: You need fix your high-res icon. It is not a valid image

Tags: android, image, icons, google-play, gimp

This is the error message I get when attempting to give my app an image on the play store. Here is the image.

[image]

It was created in GIMP. Please help, this is keeping me from getting my app up.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As described on Google Play Store developer console, icon image should be:
*512 x 512, **32-bit** PNG (with alpha)*

Your picture is (I checked with "file" Linux command)
*PNG image data, 512 x 512, **8-bit colormap**, non-interlaced*

This happened because your image uses only a few colors and gimp decided to use png format with [indexed colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_color) so image file is as small as possible.

Comment: GIMP doesn't "decide" this. This is controlled by the user, by choosing the Image->Mode.

Comment: The new app icon can be png but cannot have any transparent pixel in image.

Answer (score 3):

Resolved by re-saving with Paint.NET. I guess it's some kind of GIMP bug.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use

```
PNG image data, 512 x 512, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced
```

Answer (score 0):

if you see "Store Listing".
down.
down..
down...
there is another input box

> > Hi-res icon 
> >     Default – Korean (South Korea) – ko-KR
> >     512 x 512
> >     32-bit PNG (with alpha)

I also wasted very much time.
the solution was very, very, simple.

there is another input box.

Comment: JIC it can help someone: If you have low resolution images and want to convert them to high resolution, you could consider [this free, online webapp](https://pixlr.com/editor/). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I worked hours on this.  Finally I downloaded photo and picture resizer and you can type in the size you want.  Then take a screenshot of it and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

I have done below to solve this issue:

1. Used resize button in the mspaint / Paint application in Windows.
2. Made sure the content is in the middle of the images.

Uploaded, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

Google flagged me with this even I haven't changed our icon, only the screenshots.