# It make me crazy with Google Play Store rejected due to 'Hi-res icon' issue?

Tags: android-studio, google-play

I know the policy for the App icon of Google Play is *Transparent PNG or JPEG with 512 px by 512 px*.

I'm sure my icons fit Google's policy, you can see PNG and JPG

1: But my App icon is rejected by Google Play many times no matter to submit either PNG or JPG icon, why?

2: I submit the same icon for two different app (one is free, another is pro), one app is passed, another app is rejected due to the 'Hi-res icon' issue, why?

3: Even if I update only the new release, and I don't make any modification on *"Main store listing"* webpage, sometimes my App is rejected due to the 'Hi-res icon' issue, why?

4: Is Google Play to check  'Hi-res icon' by AI automatically, or check  'Hi-res icon' by a human?

5: Is there an online tool to guarantee to create an app icon that isn't rejected by Google Play?

**PNG**

[image]

**JPEG**

[image]

BTW, I have read many articles.

[Google Play Store: You need fix your high-res icon. It is not a valid image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158997/google-play-store-you-need-fix-your-high-res-icon-it-is-not-a-valid-image)

[Google play storelisting: You need fix your high-res icon. It is not a valid image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34531859/google-play-storelisting-you-need-fix-your-high-res-icon-it-is-not-a-valid-ima)

[High res icon and image asset studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534397/high-res-icon-and-image-asset-studio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try just saving it in paint but making it smaller. It sounds simple but paint-saved files are compatible with practically everything.

PS yes I know they don't actually save as paint files but as what format you want them too.

Comment: This is actually a really good idea. I've had the most obscure issues with optimized PNG and JPG files with React Native. Only once or twice mind you, but those one or two times burned so many hours...

Comment: Also try on a PC if you are using a mobile as a PC is guaranteed to be better at this as it could be a formatting problem.